# Lightswitch - deadlock in save pipeline

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

two days ago, I 've met deadlock in saving pipeline of Lighswitch application. I thought, it is problem with my application, but later, after some testing and reading informations about Lightswitch pipeline, I found out that isolation level Repeatable Read caused it.

Pseudo-code: 
inside of inserting method of some entity, some other entity (E1) is loaded from data source and then this entity is modified - so read-write model. If more transactions starts in the same time, deadlock can occurs:
1. Transaction A read E1
2. Transaction B read E1
3. Transaction A write E1, but wait for Transaction B
4. Transaction B write E1, but wait for Transaction A.
5. Deadlock occurs

So, if save pipeline contains read-write of some entity, you have to count with deadlock. Right?

Hovewer, simple updating entity is also read-write, but deadlock not occurs. Can somebody say me why?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is the intent lock taken when the two transactions begin.  Ideally, you'd be better off doing the reads non-transactionally, then committing the writes within more atomic transactions.